# TileService requestListeningState not working on Android Q (Couldn't find tile for ComponentInfo)

Tags: android, android-service, android-10.0

I have a [`TileService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService) that has been working before Android Q. This is the configuration to be active (controlled):

```xml
<meta-data
  android:name="android.service.quicksettings.ACTIVE_TILE"
  android:value="true" />
```

Which means I can update the tile calling [`requestListeningState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#requestListeningState(android.content.Context,%20android.content.ComponentName)). However, this is not working anymore and I see the following message in the Logcat:

```
D/TileServices: Couldn't find tile for ComponentInfo{com.my.package/com.my.package.foler.MyTileService}
```

This is the code:

```java
final ComponentName componentName = 
  new ComponentName(context, MyTileService.class);

MyTileService.requestListeningState(context, componentName);
```

I am wondering what has changed, the line to get the `ComponentName` was working just fine before Android Q. Somehow now is failing [here (Android source code)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/external/TileServices.java#163).

Another intersting thing is that if I remove the tile and I add it again, then it works for some time till the issue appears again.

Comment: That last part does not sound good. I do not see a bug related to this in the issue tracker -- if you have a sample that can demonstrate the problem, I recommend filing an issue.

Comment: The weird thing is that the system tiles are working fine, so I guess there is different way of updating it now.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this issue. I think it was a bug in some component in the OS that got updated.

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same issue, unfortunately. Comparing the ComponentInfo I get in the configuration activity and the one that's logged in the "Couldn't find tile for ComponentInfo" shows that the ComponentInfo is exactly the same. I also tried exporting my TileService to be sure, to no avail.
I have a feeling that this might be vendor-specific, as I don't have the same issue on an Android 10 emulatorm, but I do have the issue on my Android 10 OnePlus 6T